Linux kernel wait queues: may the condition check block?
I understand that in the Linux Kernel wait queues, the condition expression is evaluated after the current thread is enqueued in the waiter list. But what happens if the condition expression involves locking?
For example:

thread A calls wait_event(wq, blocking_condition) -> thread A is added to wq's queue, then blocking_condition is evaluated, which blocks on, say, a mutex. At this point thread A is blocking in two places.
thead B calls wake_up(wq)
thread A wakes up and continues, although it should still be waiting on that mutex

Is some special handling involved here (i.e. all blocking primitives in the kernel can handle spurious wake-ups) or is this pure abuse?
